# Django annotate window expression automatically getting removed while calling .get()

Tags: python, django, orm

I'm using Django ORM and want to retrieve a value after ordered queryset like below.

How do I get a value after ordered?
Django: 2.2.16
PostgreSQL: 9.6.19

```
rankings = Ranking.objects.annotate(
            rank=Window(
                expression=Rank(),
                order_by=F('count').desc()
            )
        )

# I want to get an ordered single value.
print(rankings.get(user_id=self.id).rank) <- returning only a single value, irrespective of the kwarg applied.
```

#### Update

`rankings.values("rank")`, `rankings.values_list("rank")` and iterating over the queryset (`rankings`) is also fine

Comment: What you have got? Error? Wrong result?

Comment: @JPG Wrong result. Every user got rank=1

Comment: I tried the same with *my own sample data* and it's perfectly fine. So, I would suggest you add a ***minimal verifiable example with sample data (and expected result)*** to the OP

Comment: @JPG oh, really? Thanks for trying it. Which Django version did you use? I'm using 2.2.16.
And also, you didn't load before `.get`?

Comment: Oh sorry, you are right. I was looking in the wrong direction.

Comment: As we expect, the `.get()` function supposed to return the annotated value, as in any other cases. Maybe this could be a bug.

Comment: @JPG I see. I recognized. Thank you!